# Trying to sort by custom order

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort a list order to the order of BMC-, CSR-, MC- and CSR-. This list exist on column B and has data on column C.

```
Sub telecomsorter()
Dim vCustom_Sort As Variant, rr As Long

vCustom_Sort = Array("BMC-", "CSR-", "MC-", "LC-", Chr(42))
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=vCustom_Sort

With Worksheets("TELECOM")
  LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row for the given table
Range("B13:C" & LastRow).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B13:B47"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B13:C" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End With

End Sub
```

I want the list to be in the order of:

- BMC-
- CSR-
- MC-
- LC-

[image: Table]

If there are multiple strings that are the same, then I want to sort according to the order of column C.

Comment: I would not go through the headache of doing this in VBA.  Add a sort order column.  =SWITCH(LEFT($B14,3), "BMC",1, "CSR",2, "MC-",3, "LC-",4,99) -- and then sort on it and column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try to this... I removed the array and add the sorting values directly to the Sort properties.

```
CustomOrder:="BMC-,CSR-,MC-,LC-," & Chr(42) & ""
```

```
Option Explicit
Sub telecomsorter()

Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("TELECOM")

LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B13:C" & LastRow).Select

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B14:B" & LastRow & ""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "BMC-,CSR-,MC-,LC-," & Chr(42) & "", DataOption:=xlSortNormal

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "C14:C" & LastRow & ""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B13:C" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** I couldn't figure it out why the LC- always comes before the MC-, so I made a small function to do the workaround... it may not be the ideal solution but it works.

```
Option Explicit
Sub telecomsorter()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim First As Long
Dim Last As Long

With Worksheets("TELECOM")

LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B13:C" & LastRow).Select

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B14:B" & LastRow & ""), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "BMC-*,CSR-*,MC-*,LC-*," & Chr(42) & "", DataOption:=xlSortNormal

  With ActiveSheet.Sort
      .SetRange Range("B14:C" & LastRow)
      .Header = xlNo
      .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
      .Apply
  End With

 Call SortSpecial("LC-*", xlDescending)
 Call SortSpecial("MC-*", xlAscending)
 Call SortSpecial("LC-*", xlAscending)

End With

End Sub
```

```
Public Function SortSpecial(ByVal StrVal As String, ByVal SortOrder As XlSortOrder)

  Dim First As Long
  Dim Last As Long

  First = Columns("B").Find(StrVal, , xlValues, , xlRows, xlNext, , , False).Row
  Last = Columns("B").Find(StrVal, , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious, , , False).Row

  ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
  ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B" & First & ":B" & Last), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=SortOrder, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

  With ActiveSheet.Sort

  If SortOrder = xlAscending Then
    .SetRange Range("B" & First & ":C" & Last)
  Else
  Last = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  .SetRange Range("B" & First & ":C" & Last)
  End If

    .Header = xlNo
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Apply

  End With

End Function
```

Comment: Just tried. Except, the MC-XXXXX stuff still falls after the LC-XXXXX stuff. Is there a work around?

Comment: Thanks for answering

Comment: That's it! Thanks for answering. I can't vote this up since I don't have enough reputation points, but I appreciate what you've done.

Comment: No worries, happy to help ;) @ChristopherLee